# Schröder–Bernstein Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, cardinals

> Using the  Schröder–Bernstein theorem show that (0,1) × (0,1) and (0,1) have the same cardinality.

I've just recently been introduced to cardinality and have been struggling with this question.

Comment: For the theorem, we were told that if |S| \ge |T| & |T| \ge |S|, then this implies that |S| = |T|. I was told that |S| \ge |T| implies injectivity but I'm not sure how to construct this since the question asks me to go from 2 dimensions into 1. This is where I'm having difficulty.

Comment: For clarity, the '\ge' means greater than or equal to

Comment: You will be more popular here if you learn how to present your question nicely.  Look here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.  You can practise by typing a question.  The formatted version appears below your entry.

Comment: I have only just found out about this website, I have yet to acquaint myself with how to present questions.. I do intend to learn asap

Answer (score 2):

The theorem requires you to inject each way. Injecting from one dimension to two dimensions is trivial (just add a coordinate equal to $\frac{1}{2}$). But how do we do the reverse? Here's a hint: each number in $\left( 0,\,1\right)$ has a unique decimal expansion, provided you ban infinite trailing $9$s. How can I inject from pairs of these expansions to such expansions singly?

Comment: Why is injecting from one dimension onto two dimensions trivial? For the last question, do I use a function like f(x,y)=x1y1x2y2...?

Comment: Injection is trivial: send $x$ to $(x,0.5)$.

Comment: @Roger Your choice of $f$ is correct (don't forget the $0.$, though).